# How to require ruby gems in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I've been looking all over the internet with no answer. Does anyone know how to require ruby gems in Jupyter notebook? I tried `require'byebug'` and `require 'pry'` with no use.

I get this error when I try `require 'byebug'`:

*** No sourcefile available for (pry)

And this error when I try `require 'pry'`:

From: (pry) @ line 923 Object#divide:

I'm using a local notebook and not the cloud version of course.

EDIT: I even tried setting the absolute path when requiring byebug `require '/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/byebug-9.0.6'`.

Answer (score 0):

I was having issues with this as well. I was running into this problem because I installed iruby with ruby-2.3.0 and the kernel was crashing because I didn't have the required gem rbczmq. long story short I had to install ruby version 2.3.3 and copy my gemset and make sure Iruby had registered the correct version that I was using.

1. Check what version of ruby you are using `rvm list` here you need to
   double check that you are using the version you think you are you
   can    change to the correct one with `rvm use ruby-x.x.x`.
2. Once you have decided on a ruby version check what gemset you are using. `rvm gemset list` will tell you what's available.
3. Make sure the gem is in the gem set you are using by using `gem list`. remember each gemset is brand new when you install a new ruby
   version they don't automatically get copied over.
4. (optional) copy the gemset you had been using `rvm gemset copy ruby-2.3.0 ruby-2.3.3` or you can install just the gems you want.
5. Make sure that Jupyter(Iruby) is using the correct version. Again it could be looking at a different version in which case the gem is in fact not in that gemset. Start up the notebook using `iruby notebook` and check under the new tab it should have the ruby version you expect it to if it does not you need to quit iruby and run `iruby register --force` and try it again.

That worked for me hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the gem you want is accessible at the shell/environment where you start the comand 'jupyter notebook' as it will inherit that ruby environment (even though you have already registered the ruby version via iruby register)

- On the same shell/environment you startup jupyter notebook and run 'irb -r byebug'.  Note if you also use rbenv or rvm, you need to enter that environment before startup jupyter notebook.
- If not, arrange for the gem to be available.  Depending on your working environment, could be just 'gem install', or 'bundle install', and verify again

Example with bundle.

```
# Gemfile
require 'byebug'
require 'pry'

% bundle install # To download and install

# Verify no error on command line (terminal)
$ bundle install
$ irb -r byebug -r pry
irb(main):001:0>

# Within Jupyter N
require 'byebug'
require 'pry'
```

If you have different rbenv/rvm with different gemset, jupyter notebook started under that environment will only see that dedicated gemset.  This is similar to jupyter started under different conda environment.